# pandas data frame index issues

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have downloaded the following data from yfinance api as follow:

```
import yfinance as yf
symbols=['BTC-USD', 'SPY', 'TSLA', 'AAPL', 'CAKE', 'JBLU', 'MSFT']
data = yf.download(symbols, start="2015-01-01", end="2021-04-20")
```

I tried to choose appl from the data frame ad

```
appl=data['AAPL']
```

but it did not work I don't know how pandas indexed the stock name? I can however, do high=data['High']

any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cross-section `xs`:

```
data.xs('AAPL', axis=1, level=1)
```

Output:

```
            Adj Close   Close    High     Low    Open     Volume
Date                                                            
2015-01-02      24.82   27.33   27.86   26.84   27.85  212818400
2015-01-05      24.12   26.56   27.16   26.35   27.07  257142000
2015-01-06      24.12   26.57   26.86   26.16   26.64  263188400
2015-01-07      24.46   26.94   27.05   26.67   26.80  160423600
2015-01-08      25.40   27.97   28.04   27.17   27.31  237458000
...               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...        ...
2021-04-13     134.20  134.43  134.66  131.93  132.44   91266500
2021-04-14     131.81  132.03  135.00  131.66  134.94   87222800
2021-04-15     134.27  134.50  135.00  133.64  133.82   89347100
2021-04-16     133.93  134.16  134.67  133.28  134.30   84922400
2021-04-19     134.61  134.84  135.47  133.34  133.51   94264200
```

P.S. Oddly enough, I was getting `NaN`s for some days, and removing `BTC-USD` from the list of tickers helped

---

Another option, if you want to have a ticker as top-level index in columns, you can `swaplevel` and then access Apple data with `data['APPL']`:

```
data = data.swaplevel(axis=1)
data['AAPL']
```

(same output as above)

Comment: Thanks! that solved my issue! I was wondering do you know how can I iterate in this data to find the moving average for each stock. I know that we can find the moving average from rolling.mean() but how to iterate in a for loop ?

Comment: @AMEXPO If you run `data.rolling(x).mean()` (where `x` is the window) on the DataFrame, it will do it on all columns, so you'll get moving average for each stock, so you don't need to loop

Comment: Thanks for your reply I did the following and it did not work.                             ``AV= pd.DataFrame(index=data.index)
AV['10']=data['Close'].rolling(10).mean()
AV['30']=data['Close'].rolling(30).mean() ''

Comment: @AMEXPO You just do `data['Close'].rolling(10).mean()` -- and you get 10-day moving average of Close for all tickers (one column per ticker)